# Find and remove all documents whose "createdDate" is one month older

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on `MongoDB Collections`. I have a set of collections each having many documents. I have to write a procedure to delete all those documents whose "createdDate" is older than one month from current date.

I am stuck in finding the date which is one month back of the current date in order to compare it with document's "createdDate".

Also i have to schedule this procedure, so that it can run automatically everyday. (OS is windows). How can i achieve it?

Comment: quick question before I answer this: are you sure you want to 'delete' it? It might be a better choice to 'deactivate' that data so that you can keep it for analytics purposes without it showing up in your application

Comment: also what driver or library are you using? sort of determines how i write the answer

Comment: As i am new to MongoDb, i don't have any idea that the documents can be deactivate too. I would sure like to deactivate that. And i am using java driver.

Comment: deactivation isn't inherent in mongodb, but you can have a bool on your document schema called 'active'. set this to false when you want to deactivate it, and include active:true in your queries. be sure to index this field. mongodb will mix it in with other indexes using http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try getting a date object that takes in the current date's month (bearing in mind that JavaScript month dates are 0-based index) and add 1 to get one month's date from now, which you can then use in your query with **`$gt`** operator on the `createdDate` field:

```
var now = new Date();
d = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, now.getDate());
db.collection.remove({ createdDate: { $gt: d } })
```

**UPDATE**

For your second question,

> i have to schedule this procedure, so that it can run automatically
>   everyday. (OS is windows). How can i achieve it?

MongoDB currently has no support for native Job scheduling. Most operating systems have a way to run scheduled programs like cron or Windows Task Scheduler etc so since this is quite a broad question, I can only suggest you write a custom shell script with the above that you can schedule with Windows Task Scheduler to run everyday.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. Please help me with the second problem.i have to schedule this procedure, so that it can run automatically everyday. (OS is windows). How can i achieve it?